# Is it possible to change environment variables within Batch and utilize them without restarting CMD prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to setup a system wide environment variable within my batch script script running within the CMD prompt, I have been able to achieve this by calling:

```
setx MyEnvVar "C:\<Some Path>" /M
```

However when I do:

```
echo "MyEnvVar is %MyEnvVar%"
```

afterwards the statement that outputs at prompt is "MyEnvVar is" although the variable has been setup with setx and I can observe it through looking at the Windows - system properties - environment variables GUI.

I know this is because the CMD prompt has to be restarted for it to pick up the new environment variables however I don't want to stop the execution of my batch script and tell the user to manually restart the CMD prompt window and re-run my script so the environment variables are picked up. Is there some other way of getting around this?

It would be better if I could get around this without utilizing the "call" method and breaking the script to two segments

batchfileA - Code up until and including the call to change the environment variables thereafter utilize call method to call batchfileB
batchfileB- The rest of the original code placed inside batchfileB and called with call method within batchfileA

Comment: Of course `setx /m` doesn't propagate to the current process. Use `set` to set a variable in the current cmd.exe process. Of course it would be more helpful if you would expand your question to explain _what_ you are trying to do rather than _how_.

Comment: The batch file could call itself.  The first few lines of the  script could check to see the env variable is set, and if so, continue from there.  But this would be hacky.  Perhaps better to use set instead of setx as Bill and Alex suggest?

Comment: Yes you guys are correct the problem I had was I had tried using set after the setx and echoed the result and the variable was null so I assumed that the value was not taking because I had to restart the CMD prompt what I forgot was I had enabled DelayedExpansion and had to use ! (exclamation marks) instead of % (percent) signs around my variable names. That did the trick. Thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried using set after the setx and echoed the result and the variable was null so I assumed that the value was not taking because I had to restart the CMD prompt what I forgot was I had enabled DelayedExpansion and had to use ! (exclamation marks) instead of % (percent) signs around my variable names